# How can I use default with variable in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I know that I can use a simple hardcoded string in default but I am trying to do this:

```
myvar: "{{ lookup('env','var1') | default("{{var2}}",true) }}"
```

But it adds that as a string instead of evaluating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you opened a Jinja2 expression with `{{` you don't need to open it again (especially quoted) and you can refer to the variables by their names:

```
myvar: "{{ lookup('env','var1') | default(var2, true) }}"
```